# Execute foreach loop on clicking a button in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, button, onclick

I wish if I click button *Today* then loop related to today would be displayed and if the button *month* is clicked then foreach loop for month should be displayed.

Here is my controller:

```
public function render()
{
    $this->today=Order_Detail::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
    $this->todaySale=Order_Detail::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->sum('amount');
    $this->month=Order_Detail::whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))->get();
    $this->montlySale=Order_Detail::whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))->sum('amount');
    return view('livewire.order');
}
```

Here is my order.blade.php code:

```
<!-- Today -->
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><h4 style="float:left">Recent Orders</h4>
 
 </div>
<div class="card-body">              
    <Table class="table table-bordered table-left">

    <div style="float:right">
    <button type="button" onclick="" id="today" >Today</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="" id="today" >Month</button>
    </div>

      <tbody>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Product id</th>
        <th>Order Id</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Date and Time</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <div id="todayTag">
      <label for="">Total Sale Today {{$todaySale}}</label>
      @foreach($today as $today)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$today->product_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->order_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->product->product_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->unitprice}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->amount}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->discount}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->created_at}}</td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        </div>

       <div id="monthTag">
      <label for="">Total Sale by Month {{$montlySale}}</label>
        @foreach($month as $month)
          <tr>
          <td>{{$month->product_id}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->order_id}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->product->product_name}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->quantity}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->unitprice}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->amount}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->discount}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->created_at}}</td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
          <div>

        <tbody>
        </Table> 

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest a way to put my loops inside of my buttons? through livewire, javascript or any? I have searched a lot but couldn't do it.

Comment: If this is a JavaScript question why are you a) tagging laravel and php and b) not posting just pure HTML CSS and JavaScript? - what does `then loop related to today would be displayed in form` even mean?

Comment: Note that you can't wrap a `<form>` around a `<tr>`. It makes it invalid table markup

Comment: @mplungjan  Please read the last line: *Please suggest a way to put my loops inside of my buttons? through livewire, javascript or any?* I tagged laravel to know if it could be done in livewire , using a specific language is not the concern because I am just a beginner I just want to do it in any language . I have edited line you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: @charlietfl I have replaced it with a div now

Comment: That is just as invalid as the form was. A tr must be in either tbody, thead etc or table. Same with `<div>` being invalid child of tbody

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please suggest what should I use here? to have an id for my js onclick event? One idea I got now is to use multiple <tbody> tags to put one loop in one <tbody>  like this:<tbody id="todayTag"> will it be helpful? or please suggest?

Comment: What are you wanting exactly....click on  a row and get details from that row to send via ajax?

Comment: @charlietfl no i just simply want to display table contained in foreach loop inside of a button, means if i click the button then data of foreach loop should be displayed.....

Comment: Well the button is in the browser and that foreach loop is on the server so it's a bit more complicated than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming there's no table displayed by default and that you have to click a button first before showing one, I suggest you remove the `Today` and `Month` buttons from the table and put it right after the `card-body` div and right before your table, like this:

```
<div class="card-body"> 
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('todayTable').style.display ='block'; document.getElementById('monthTable').style.display ='none';" id="today">Today</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('todayTable').style.display ='none'; document.getElementById('monthTable').style.display ='block';"  id="month">Month</button>             
<table class="table table-bordered table-left">
```

As for your tables, you can do it like this:

```
// Today Table

 <table class="table table-bordered table-left" id="todayTable" style="display: none;">
      <tbody>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Product id</th>
        <th>Order Id</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Date and Time</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

      <label for="">Total Sale Today {{$todaySale}}</label>
      @foreach($today as $today)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$today->product_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->order_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->product->product_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->unitprice}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->amount}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->discount}}</td>
        <td>{{$today->created_at}}</td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach  
      </tbody>
        </table> 


// Month Table

 <table class="table table-bordered table-left" id="monthTable" style="display: none;">
      <tbody>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Product id</th>
        <th>Order Id</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Date and Time</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

    <label for="">Total Sale by Month {{$montlySale}}</label>
        @foreach($month as $month)
          <tr>
          <td>{{$month->product_id}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->order_id}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->product->product_name}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->quantity}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->unitprice}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->amount}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->discount}}</td>
          <td>{{$month->created_at}}</td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
          <div>
      </tbody>
        </table>
```

With this, tables show and hide according to the button clicked.